# How to characterize a distribution of values?

Tags: statistics, distribution, data-analysis

I try to explain it with an example.

In a school there are n classes. In each classe there are k students, with k from 1 to 700, both n and k are known.

I need a way to characterize, for each class, the distribution of the names of students. For example, in class A there are 10 students, 3 are named "John", 3 "Mark" and 3 "Anne". In another class there are 100 student and everyone is named "Anton".

I need a measure able to be indicative of names distribution in each class. For example, (it's not important), it may be 1 if everyone in a class has the same name and 0 if there aren't 2 identical names in the same class.

In other words a way to sort classes by the distribution of names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want a "[contingency table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table)".  It's arbitrary which of your variables you want to have as rows vs. columns, but the table entries are either counts or proportions of how many occurrences fall in the intersection of the categories.

With the example you gave:

```
                     Class
                  A        B
              _________________
       Anne  |    3   |    0   |   3
Names  Anton |    0   |  100   | 100
       John  |    3   |    0   |   3
       Mark  |    3   |    0   |   3
    Unknown  |    1   |    0   |   1
             |--------|--------|----
                 10      100   | 110
```

Values at the right and along the bottom are called the "marginal totals", or if proportions, "marginal distributions".  The bottom right corner is the grand total of your data, obtained by summing the row or column margins. (They better come out the same!) For proportions, the sum must be 1.